# How to make this sound?

Tags: replication

http://www57.zippyshare.com/v/k41qnbXF/file.html

Sounds a bit like 303 acid but more natural and ''talky'' than usual. Does anyone know synths that sounds like that?

Comment: What have you already tried and why didn't it give you the proper results?

Comment: The sound sample is a bit too short to figure out where the sound starts. It is quite possibly a vocoder effect, but it is difficult to estimate carrier and modulator sources in this short sample. A plate reverb seems also to obscure the original sound making the sample even more metallic.

Answer (score -1):

I think that it isn't about synthesizer, you need to add effect in chain. Vocoder or talkbox - you can even try with envelope LF and bitcrush a little bit, but I think that using as example TAL Vocoder on any acid synth will give similar results.

Comment: Welcome to sound.SE. We prefer answers that actually go into some detail to adress the specific question (“more natural...”). Yours is more of a _comment_ right now (once you have enough reputation, you can post those too); please extend it so it actually makes a full answer.